# selected item not showing up in jquery mobile select - nativedroid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

[image]

Even if i select an item in the select list it doesn't show up on the select box.

Please find below my code for the css:

```
    <li class="ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="select-choice-1b" class="select">Type:</label>
     <div class="ui-select">
    <div class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <select len="50" calculated="false" related_module="" required="" id_name="" group="" type="enum" name="account_type" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
    <option value="Competitor">Competitor</option>
    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
    <option value="Integrator">Integrator</option>
    <option value="Investor">Investor</option>
    <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
    <option value="Press">Press</option>
    <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
    <option value="Reseller">Reseller</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Please help i am new to jquery mobile.

Comment: Looking at the code from Nativedroid theme select should be like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/7rhFr/ -- can you try that example a see if you can select ok. Those Divs you have in between i assume are for styles maybe that's whats causing the problem.

Comment: if i remove the divs i don't get any styling in my select's

Comment: i am generating my form dynamically so also applying all the styles through jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting the jQM CSS yourself, just add the regular HTML markup and then call **[.enhanceWithin()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** on the containing DOM element to force jQM to add all the styling and functionality.

Given this page markup:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The following script will dynamically add a listview with a select box in the first listitem:

```
var dyn = '<ul data-role="listview"><li><select name="account_type" id="account_type" data-native-menu="false"><option value=""></option><option value="Analyst">Analyst</option><option value="Competitor">Competitor</option><option value="Customer">Customer</option><option value="Integrator">Integrator</option><option value="Investor">Investor</option><option value="Partner">Partner</option><option value="Press">Press</option><option value="Prospect">Prospect</option><option value="Reseller">Reseller</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select></li></ul>';

$("#container").empty().append(dyn).enhanceWithin();
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6ZcyG/)**

Comment: i tried the trigger.create element instead of .enhanceWithin() it works too thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome. enhanceWithin is new to version 1.4